# Does i need to apply Sessions in ASP.NET for log in/log out if im using SimpleMembership in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, authentication, logout, simplemembership

I am new to web development so, do i need to implement sessions while i am using SimpleMembership 
as i was having problem with back button after logs out. It goes to the previous page instead of  login. So I added code below in global.ascx. It works perfect now!!

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1));
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

So my query is, can i run my application without sessions in which there is  **Authentication** of users i.e. there are user accounts and login and logout functionality is there.

Answer (score 0):

You can login and logout by using default `SimpleMembership` functions:

For Login:

```
bool success = WebSecurity.Login(form["username"], form["password"], false);
```

For Logout:

```
 WebSecurity.Logout();
```

For details refer MSDN link [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simplemembershipprovider%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)

Comment: well you just misinterpreted my question , MY question was does i need to apply sessions in my application or SimpleMembership is enough to handel what sessions provide e.g after logout back button takes the user to main page

Comment: SimpleMemebership is enough to handle login and logout.